# MySql updating table using cmd and getting the % value of one column

Tags: mysql, syntax, cmd

I want to edit the salary of all the customers by getting 0.25% who are born by before 1985 so here is the table.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7NAf.jpg

what'd be the syntax to get this value?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFIjn.jpg

I will appreciate every answer thankyou :)

Comment: You don't have the birth date field there, no way to know when each was born...

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/9YBap im sorry here is table #2 i dont have 10 reputations to post more than 2 links :(

Comment: is it a one-to-on table? custeomers.id == birthdates.id?

Comment: yes, and thankyou denvenv :) !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE customers, births
SET salary = salary * 0.25
WHERE customers.id = births.id AND birth < "1985"
```

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN birth_dates ON customers.id = birth.customer_id
WHERE bir' at line 3
MariaDB [test]>

What should i edit to make it run?
Here is the two tables; 
http://imgur.com/a/GGNf9

Comment: Forgot that maria doesn't support joins in updates, try this one